# neovim colors not "just working"

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting, neovim

I have some simple (default) syntax highlighting, and other colors, in my regular vim. I'd like to try out neovim, so I did the

```
cd && ln -s .vimrc .nvimrc && ln -s .vim .nvim
```

I'm currently on ubuntu, and installed neovim from the ppa at:
https://launchpad.net/~neovim-ppa

(I can paste the contents of nvim -v, if needed)

Here is the old vim colors - note the line numbers, and the green of minibufexplorer:

[image: Original vim colors]

And here is what it looks like with nvim. It is doing *some* syntax highlighting, but not nearly what the original vim did.

[image: Neovim colors]

I was hoping this would be a simple drop-in replacement, but doesn't appear that way currently. I might certainly have something misconfigured in my system.

I also tried

```
export VIMRUNTIME=/usr/share/vim/vim74
```

to no avail. The entirety of my .vimrc is:

```
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
syntax on
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Check your TERM variable. It should be something like xterm-256color

Comment: YUP. That's it. Thanks! If there's anything I can do more than upvote your comment, let me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check your TERM variable. It needs to be set to something like `xterm-256color` which says that the terminal supports 256 colors.